# I am trying to get some guidance on how to move (or copy) a row into another workbook based on cell value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I am trying to automate a process in Google Apps which involves moving or copying (whichever is the more efficient process) a row of data from a master sheet titled "Prospects" into one of four workbooks titled "G1Targets","G2Targets", "G3Targets", "G4Targets" based on a cell value in the Prospects sheet.

Each row in the Prospects sheet has a salesman id (G1, G2, G3, G4) associated with it in column 4.  I want to be able to move (or copy) the row from the Prospects sheet to the next blank row in the relevant G?Targets workbook.

I have found quite a few code snippets that deal with copying between sheets within the same workbook and copying entire ranges but nothing that deals with individual rows placed in next blank rows.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: "slave workbooks" & "master sheet". These are not terms in general use; please edit your question to be more precise about whether/when you are referring to spreadsheets (files) or sheets (tabs/pages)? "... and move or copy the row..." - 'move' is not the same as 'copy' - which do you want? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> If your sheets are all located withing the same spreadsheet, you can use the methods [moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget), whereby you can use a row
>   as a range, a conditional statement to decide in which sheet to copy
>   the data and [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow), to know where to append the data. This code should work for you:

```
function moveRows() {
 var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXX');
 var mastersheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master');
 var G1=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('G1Targets');
 var G2=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('G2Targets');
 var G3=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('G3Targets');
 var G4=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('G4Targets');
 var counter=mastersheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn=mastersheet.getLastRow();
  var sheetName=mastersheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  for (var i=1; i<=counter; i++)
  {   
    var range=mastersheet.getRange(i,2,1,lastColumn)
    if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G1"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="G2"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="G3"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="G4"){
    if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G1")
       {
         var target=G1;
       }
    else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G2")
      {
         var target=G2;
       }
    else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G3")
      {
         var target=G3;
       }                 
     else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G4")
      {
         var target=G4;
       }
    var lastRow=target.getLastRow();
    range.moveTo(target.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,lastColumn-1));
    }  
  }  
}
```

> If your sheets are located in different spreadsheets, you can copy the
>   rows (e.g. with `getValues()` and `setValues()`) and subsequently erase
>   them from the master sheet:

```
function setValues() {
 var mastersheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZmlLY4eHFS7eMsoqnyPPsmiW0EXth0KX7WJIWu-oiX8').getSheetByName('Master');
 var G1=SpreadsheetApp.openById('17C0SUTlMbx9WoSWluu8lM3gRBvSm7heDmlrW9jOgUF8').getSheetByName('G1Targets');
 var G2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZmlLY4eHFS7eMsoqnyPPsmiW0EXth0KX7WJIWu-oiX8').getSheetByName('G2Targets');
 var G3=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZmlLY4eHFS7eMsoqnyPPsmiW0EXth0KX7WJIWu-oiX8').getSheetByName('G3Targets');
 var G4=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZmlLY4eHFS7eMsoqnyPPsmiW0EXth0KX7WJIWu-oiX8').getSheetByName('G4Targets');
 var counter=mastersheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn=mastersheet.getLastRow();
  var sheetName=mastersheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  for (var i=1; i<=counter; i++)
  {   
    var range=mastersheet.getRange(i,2,1,lastColumn)
    if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G1"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="G2"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="G3"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="G4"){
    if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G1")
       {
         var target=G1;
       }
    else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G2")
      {
         var target=G2;
       }
    else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G3")
      {
         var target=G3;
       }                 
     else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="G4")
      {
         var target=G4;
       }
    var lastRow=target.getLastRow();
    target.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,lastColumn).setValues(range.getValues());
    range.clear();  
    }  
  }   

}
```

Comment: You are right,if your sheets are not located within the same spreadsheet, it is not possible to use moveTo(). A workaround would be to only copy the rows instead of moving and the then clear the contents in the master sheet. I update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Excellent.  That worked fantastically.  If I wanted to paste the copied value from column 5 onwards in the target sheet is it this piece that I would adjust? target.getRange(lastRow+1,5,1,lastColumn).setValues(range.getValues());

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this.  I have adjusted it slightly with spreadsheet ids and sheet names.  When I run it I get the following error - Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. (line 31, file "AssignNewProspects").  This is the adjusted code

```
    function myFunction() {
 var mastersheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UQCmsYZFhbgEc-kWTqnL_Acb1AI60ZKKExNaLKla7so').getSheetByName('New Targets');
 var DT=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1S54dKvh2crGyJeOBNeOhuE3mNU1HSwuipiYNabtNVLs').getSheetByName('Prospects_DT');
 var JM=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1h9hFJlmR752azA4PqkWq_DpKgKkjfvnFsd_7oDy1zw0').getSheetByName('Prospects_JM');
 var RC=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1txH9T9_Gqicp-ZIA27k-C9EyOYdDIyXcYcS7br_DMkM').getSheetByName('Prospects_RC');
 var PH=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qbyKMg5extIyz-dAjoXLtUZM_oNfRHvD5Ncj-6JB_ks').getSheetByName('Prospects_PH');
 var counter=mastersheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn=mastersheet.getLastRow();
  var sheetName=mastersheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  for (var i=1; i<=counter; i++)
  {   
    var range=mastersheet.getRange(i,2,1,lastColumn)
    if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="DT"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="JM"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="RC"||sheetName[i-1][0]=="PH"){
    if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="DT")
       {
         var target=DT;
       }
    else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="JM")
      {
         var target=JM;
       }
    else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="RC")
      {
         var target=RC;
       }                 
     else if(sheetName[i-1][0]=="PH")
      {
         var target=PH;
       }
    var lastRow=target.getLastRow();
    range.moveTo(target.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,lastColumn-1));
    }  
  }  
}
```